# Jquery if window.width()<780 only works when I resize the page. Doesn't work on phone all the time

Tags: jquery, window, size

I would greatly appreciate your help on this.
I have 2 divs that need to change position when website becomes 780px width.
I have the following code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(jQuery(window).bind("resize", listenWidth));

function listenWidth(e) {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 780) {
      jQuery("#pgc-107-1-0").remove().insertAfter(jQuery("#pgc-107-1-1"));
    } else {

      jQuery("#pgc-107-1-0").remove().insertBefore(jQuery("#pgc-107-1-1"));


    }
```

This only works when I manually resize the window and sometimes on mobile phones android or ios.  Any suggestions as to how to make this insertAfter before the window loads?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** no need to pass `e` in `function listenWidth(e) {` just use `function listenWidth() {`

**2nd:** just run the function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  listenWidth();  //<<<<<<<
  jQuery(window).on("resize", listenWidth)); // i used .on()  instead of .bind()
});
```

Comment: Thanks simple enough.